# Treeview not displaying in Windows form .net 4.8

Tags: treeview

We have a legacy Windows application from .net framework 3.5 and we are upgrading it to .net framework 4.8. One issue we are facing is we have a treeview where its data is automatically filled up and displayed when the form is first loaded in form_load() event. However when upgrading to .net 4.8 it does not show up automatically until we do loading it again.

Nothing has been changed in the code as below

treeView1.BeginUpdate();

treeView1.Nodes.Add()...

treeView1.EndUpdate()

I have tried several below ways but still not working:

- select a node by treeView1.SelectedNode after EndUpdate()
- Invalidate()
- Refresh()
- Update()

The weird thing is if we do it exactly the same via a button click after form loaded then it worked.

Any helps?
Thanks,
Kelvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI
I have put the tree data loading into form Shown event and it works.